# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I keep getting this error and I don't know why. It takes me to this line here and I cannot seem to find the issue:

```js
let categories;
            if (!this.client.owners.includes(message.author.id)) {
                categories = this.client.utils.removeDuplicates(this.client.commands.filter(cmd => cmd.category !== 'Owner').map(cmd => cmd.category));
            } else {
                categories = this.client.utils.removeDuplicates(this.client.commands.map(cmd => cmd.category));
            }
```

Comment: Obviously `this.client.owners` is not defined at the moment when this line of code is executing

Comment: Try checking **this.client.owners** again

Comment: you can try by logging value of `this.client.owners` before using it in 'if' condition. It should be an array for the condition to work as expected